# make each line 500 of file characters long

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

we need to change a file so that each line is exactly 500 characters. it means I should calculate the current line lenght and somehow add empty bytes or espaces? that each line is exactly 500 bytes.
the files have generally 3 lines so the total size of the file should be around 1500 bytes.

when i calculate the lines lenght with awk on a test file I get several variable lines lenghts:

```
awk '{ print length() }' BadFIle.txt
28
250
38
```

I should instead get this:

```
awk '{ print length() }' GoodFIle.txt
500
500
500
```

my Question clearly is how to add the remainder characters to each line so that the size is exactly 500 bytes/characters?

thank you

Mario.

Comment: what if some of your original lines is longer than 500?

Comment: the lines in our case will never be bigger than 500...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad spaces using awk:

```
awk -v n=500 '{ printf "%-*.*s\n", n, n, $0 }' file
```

OR else:

```
awk -v n=500 '{ printf "%-" n "." n "s\n", $0 }' file
```

Both these commands will do following:

1. Truncate your line to 500 if is more than 500 and
2. Pad with spaces on right hand is line width is less than 500

Comment: Hello,

Thank you I forgot to add the system is running solaris.. Do this work on solaris...

Comment: @user2653557 Solaris is just a box. On that box there are at least 3 awks. One of those awks is old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk aka oawk) which must never be used. The above should work with the other 2 - nawk and /usr/xpg4/bin/awk.

Comment: @anubhava - why specify the line length twice with a "." in between? I'd have expected a simple `printf "%-*s\n", n, $0` but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @EdMorton: I believe `printf "%-*.*s\n"` both pads and truncates to make width exactly `n` characters and `printf "%-*s\n"` only pads but lets `>n` line width print with more width than `n`.

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you very much for your assistance.. 

One last request.. is it possible to edit the file instead of displaying the results to stdout? I know that I can redirect the output to a file but there is possibility to do an 'in-place' replace with awk?

Comment: awk doesn't have in-place editing like sed so unfortunately you will need to save output in file and then move it back.. one liner is: `awk -v n=500 '{ printf "%-" n "." n "s\n", $0 }' file > _tmp && mv _tmp file`